# How to solve fatal: Could not read from remote repository in GIT?

Tags: git, gitlab, repository, ssh-keys

I have a problem in git clone ssh, when I execute make init-dev

```
if [ ! -d "goodcommerce-hydra" ] ; then git clone "git@gitlab.com:/goodcommerce/goodcommerce-hydra.git" "goodcommerce-hydra"; cd goodcommerce-hydra && git checkout "master"; fi
Cloning into 'goodcommerce-hydra'...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.com;c: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

but when I execute

```
git clone "git@gitlab.com:/goodcommerce/goodcommerce-hydra.git" "goodcommerce-hydra"
```

it works well.

maybe is de **;c** in *ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.com;c:* ?

I'm using WINDOWS 10 pro

Answer (score 2):

I think the ";" is wrong here

This should do; though "git check" doesn't seems to be a correct command.

```
if [ ! -d "goodcommerce-hydra"" ]; then 
git clone "git@gitlab.com:/goodcommerce/goodcommerce-hydra.git" "goodcommerce-hydra"" && cd goodcommerce-hydra && git check 
fi
```

Comment: excuse me, copy wrong, I already edited the question.